# Search custom form with post request datatable not working

Tags: datatable, datatables, django-datatable

Hello everyone can i search with post request in datatables?

```
backend -> django
frontend -> html/css jquery
```

In backed django I'm using the `django_serverside_datatable` library for populating data.
Please guide me. I see in datatables no option for post searching if you know anyway please let me know.i read `https://datatables.net/` but no option for handling post request on my custom form and populating data into existing table.
I make a custom form have two fields username and email and i make a button form search if i click on search button then i search by email or username by my own post request and populate the data into table. i search data using post method of form not GET method of form

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you are asking. What do you mean by "search a form with a POST request"? What do you mean by "search a form" regardless of "with a POST request"? What is the connection between "populating data into a DataTable" and the rest of your question about searching a form?

Comment: You can provide a [mre] and clarify the problem.

Comment: @andrewJames I make a custom form have two fields
username and email
and i make a button form search

if i click on search button then i search by email or username by my own post request and populate the data into table.

i search data using post method of form not GET method of form.
hope you understand now.